# Passing static field values to WSDL with JAX-WS

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, xml-attribute

I would need to set an attribute value in the WSDL for a JAX-WS WebService. I found that this can be done using the @XmlAttribute annotation for a "public static final" field of a complex type, but how do I actually pass the value from my class to the WSDL? For example, I have a class that is used as an argument for a method:

```
@XmlType(name = "argument")
public class Argument {

    @XmlAttribute
    public static final int fixer = 7;

}
```

This would create the following WSDL:

```
<xs:attribute name="fixer" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
```

But what I need is:

```
<xs:attribute name="fixer" type="xs:int" use="required" fixed=7/>
```

How to accomplish this using JAX-WS annotation?

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: added 'final' modifier

Comment: Though you say the attribute is *final* in your question, the code shows a *non-final* attribute. Are you sure you have a *final* attribute in your code?

Comment: You are correct - it is final, I fiddled with the code and must have copied the wrong version.

Comment: I managed to find (somewhere) that this is no longer allowed - adding fixed values to WSDLs. Can someone at least confirm this?